# Select rows that matches multiple and/or conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, having, where-in

So I created a sql fiddle to explain my problem much clearer:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3122282/1

As you can see I have 3 tables and 1 of them links the 2 others.

I want to make it so if I say "give me the products that is (color green OR red) and PET (dog)"?

I tried doing:

```
select `ptl`.`product_id` 
from `tags` inner join `tags` as `ptl` 
on `tags`.`id` = `ptl`.`tag_id`
where ((`tags`.`tag` = "color" and `tags.value` in ("green", "red")) 
   or (`tags`.`tag` = "pet" and `tags.value` in ("dog"))) 
having count(distinct `ptl.tag_id`) = 2
```

// 2 in that case is the number of tag "category".

but this doesn't seem to work. since having is just checking the count, it will also return the products with 2 color tags without any pet.

Comment: can you actually share your query that runs on the fiddle link that you sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the 3 tables, group by product and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_tags_link pt ON pt.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING SUM(t.tag = 'color' AND t.value IN ('green', 'red')) > 0
   AND SUM(t.tag = 'pet' AND t.value IN ('dog')) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=186985927ca72310eb255e804c74a5a1).

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining tags table with product_tags_link and products.
Take this query as a base and add the conditions on the where clause

```
select *
from products p
inner join product_tags_link ptl on ptl.product_id = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = ptl.tag_id
where CONDITIONS
```

a CONDITIONS that can be taken as example

```
p.id = 1 and t.tag = 'color' and t.value = 'green'
```

Comment: How would you write the conditions for: "give me the products that is (color green OR red) and PET (dog)"?